# Como remover elementos de uma lista em javascript

Tags: javascript, lista, dom

Estou fazendo um pequeno programa em javascript para gerar uma tabuada. Para evitar que ocorra duplicatas, eu coloco um pequeno trecho de código para limpar a lista antes de gerar a tabuada

```
 let numero = window.document.getElementById('numero');
    if (numero.value.length != 0) {
        let tabuada = window.document.getElementById('lista');
        let itens = window.document.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            tabuada.removeChild(itens[i]);
        }
```

Entretanto, a lista não é gerada se mantenho esse código. Aqui está o código completo:

```
let numero = window.document.getElementById('numero');
if (numero.value.length != 0) {
    let tabuada = window.document.getElementById('lista');
    let itens = window.document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        tabuada.removeChild(itens[i]);
    }
    let novo = window.document.createElement("li");
    tabuada.appendChild(novo);
    let section = window.document.getElementById('section');
    section.style.height = "auto";
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        let novo = window.document.createElement("li");
        let txtnovo = window.document.createTextNode(`${Number(numero.value)}x${i} = ${Number(numero.value) * i}`);
        novo.appendChild(txtnovo);
        tabuada.appendChild(novo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('btnGerar').addEventListener('click', () => {
 let numero = window.document.getElementById('numero');
 
 if (numero.value.length === 0) {
  return;
 }
 
 let tabuada = window.document.getElementById('lista');
 while(tabuada.children.length > 0) {
  tabuada.removeChild(tabuada.children[0]);
 }
 
 let novo = window.document.createElement("li");
 tabuada.appendChild(novo);

 for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  let novo = window.document.createElement("li");
  let txtnovo = window.document.createTextNode(`${Number(numero.value)}x${i} = ${Number(numero.value) * i}`);
  novo.appendChild(txtnovo);
  tabuada.appendChild(novo);
 }
});
```

```html
<input id="numero" value="3" />
<input type="button" value="gerar" id="btnGerar" />
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

Comment: Funcionou. Mas o seguinte trecho de código: while(tabuada.children.length > 0) {
  tabuada.removeChild(tabuada.children[0]);
 } eu não entendi bem. Pq a remoção acontece sempre na primeira posição dos filhos de "tabuada"? O java script realoca os restantes automáticamente?

Comment: @Matheus10772 Este trecho que você citou é para remover os `<li>` dentro do `<ul>`. Imagine que o `<ul>` tenha 3 `<li>`, logo seu `children.length` será igual a 3. Ao remover o `children[0]` o `length` será igual a 2. Depois removemos novamente o `children[0]` e o `length` passará a ser 1 e assim por diante até que não haja mais `<li>` dentro do `<ul>`. Funciona como uma pilha de papel, você sempre vai removendo o primeiro papel da pilha até que não haja mais nenhum.

Comment: Obrigado !!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem uma lista:

```
<ul id="lista">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Para remover os elementos da lista (todos os `<li>`) não precisa fazer laço usando `.removeChild()` para isso. Basta esvaziar o `.innerHTML` do elemento:

```
let tabuada = window.document.getElementById('lista');
tabuada.innerHTML = ''; // esvazia a ul#lista
```